# How can cerr (c++) turn up in Stdout (Java)?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I've got a Java application that calls a DLL written in C++ via JNI, this DLL then dynamically loads another DLL. Somehow messages written to cerr in C++ turn up in some cases on some computers in the Stdout-Stream of the Java part. There is no explicit redirection of any of the standard streams (cerr, cout, Stdout, Sterr etc.) in either the C++ part nor in the Java part.

How can this happen? How can I ensure that the cerr-stream of the C++ layer ends up in the Stderr-stream of the Java layer?

The JVM is in all cases the same,

JRE version: 6.0_27-b07, Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.2-b06 mixed mode windows-x86 )

Comment: Most probably this can be due to the JVM being implemented in `c++`

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati why should that matter?

Comment: Since the JVM is implemented in the `c++` the Java Layer will be on the top of the c++ layer. So what I think is probably this is happening since the Java Layer is reading the console on which the C++ messages are printed. This can also happen because since the errors posted by the `jni dll` are being monitored by the JVM.

Comment: I don't think that the JVM is the problem, I will add the version to my question, it is the same in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question directly, std::cerr can only show up in System.out if they share the same descriptor.

If it genuinely happens on some computers and not others, I'd suspect differences in the Java implementations of default System.out and System.err.  You did not indicate identical Java installations, just different computers.  Java makes no guarantee about its default output stream implementations.

Now, because the buffering and file descriptors on each side are uncoordinated with each other, only two possibilities exist:

1) You have access to the DLL source and can change all I/O to utilize your passed in System.out/err Java streams.

2) You don't.  At that point, even if you apparently succeed through cooperative flushing, you cannot prove correctness beyond experimental evidence that your hack appears to work.  There is a good chance that experimentation will not uncover corner cases where buffers are exactly full, empty, or when they share the same file descriptor.

Hopefully you are able to choose #1.